# Undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chat, social-media

I am trying to merge two apps together and add messaging to my program.

However, after following two tutorials I am stuck. I get this error:

> undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass on here:

Code:

```
</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <%= render 'shared/links' %>
  </div>
<% @users.each_with_index do |index| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= index +=1 %></td>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "Send Message", "#", class: "btn btn-success btn-xs start-conversation",
...
```

I am using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.5.0

Here are the two tutorials:

http://josephndungu....n-ruby-on-rails

https://github.com/scaffeinate/socify

The social media part works no problem but the chat part doesn't work.

Comment: `@users` value is nil. Please check `@users` instance variable in respective controller.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you can check `@users` value:

```
<% if @uses.present? %>
  <% @users.each_with_index do |index| %>
      <tr>
        ...
      </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or give `@users` a value if its `nil`:

```
# In controller:
@users = User.where(...) || []
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `each_with_index` iterate over two arguments one is index and second is array object
so here your syntax should be like this: -

```
  <% unless @users.blank?%>
    <%@users.each_with_index do |user, index|%>
      <%= index +=1 %>
      <%=user.name%>
      #.... and so on
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
```

make sure that `@users` are defined in your action